# How to add a white space

Tags: javascript

I want know how to add white space in JavaScript. I have this line of code:

```
document.write('<tr align="center"><td>' + txt2.bold().fontcolor("blue") +"                   "+ '</td><td>' +"                   "+  txt3.bold().fontcolor("blue") + '</td></tr><br>');
```

I want it to do it a different way is there something that I can do to add white space such as Java's "printf()" function where u can add space but doing %s-25 and it will add 25 spaces

Comment: You could use a for loop that loops 25 times and adds a space each time. But that's probably not what you're looking for

Comment: why not 25 &nbsp; ??? do you really need spaces, have you looked into css styles?

Comment: You know all but one of those spaces will be ignored, right?

Comment: im have a css style but i cant get it working 100% for me

Comment: yeah its just an example

Comment: no i need it in document.write() not console.log()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) :

```
new Array(20).join(' ')
```

or with non-breaking spaces :

```
new Array(20).join('&nbsp;')
```

Comment: how would i print that in document.write?

Comment: Like that : document.write('Some spaces : ' + new Array(20).join('&nbsp;'));